# Separar array e salvar em strings para uso posterior

Tags: c, arduino

Eu tenho um laço `for`* que conta de **1** a **8** e guarda em uma *array* chamada `str`, mas eu gostaria que quando a variável `str` chegar a 8 seja guardado o valor de `str[i]` no *array* `str_line[b]`;

Exemplo:

1. O laço `for` inicia
2. Vai guardando a cada ciclo o valor em `str[i]`
3. Quando i=8 guarda tudo que foi acumulado até agora em `str[i]` e guarda em `str_line[b]`
4. Incrementa o `b`
5. Zera o `i` e começa tudo de novo
6. Quando o `b` estiver em **5**, para o laço `for`

O programa faria isso durante sua execução:

```
str[1] = 1
str[2] = 11
str[3] = 111
str[4] = 1111
str[5] = 11111
str[6] = 111111
str[7] = 1111111
str[8] = 11111111

Guarda tudo que estiver em `str[8]` em `str_linha[1]`;

Incrementa o `b*`

E repete isso até o laço FOR fizer isso 5 vezes.
```

Não estou conseguindo transferir o valor de `str[8]` para `str_line[1]`, como eu posso fazer?

Meu código até agora:

```
char str[9];
char str_line[6];
int i;
int b;

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   str[i] = '0' + i;
   Serial.println(str);


   if(i = 8)
   {
       //Aqui guardaria o valor em str_line.

       //Zera o ponteiro e começa a contagem do FOR desde o inicio
       i = 0;

   elseif(b = 5)
   {
       //Para o laço FOR
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Acho este código esquisito, eu faria de outra forma, mas vamos lá:

```
char str[9];
char str_line[6][9];
for (int i = 0, b = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   str[i] = '0' + i;
   Serial.println(str);
   if (i == 8) {
       str[8] = '\0';
       memcpy(str_line[b], str, 9);
       i = 0;
       if (++b == 5) break;
   }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SplitFix.c).

Não testei, mas basicamente é isto. Pode existir outros erros não detectados. Não sei exatamente qual é o resultado esperado.

Comment: Olá bigown, Obrigado. Bacana, mas como guardar o valor de str[8] em em outra array, por exemplo str_line[b] ?

Comment: Pronto. Achei que o problema era só o fluxo, a sintaxe que está toda errada.

Comment: Obrigado, Eu testei aqui o codigo e tentei imprimir o str_line[3], mas não sta guardando nada, oque será ?